# Not able to connect Firebase with php

Tags: wordpress, firebase

I am using firebase as backend in php, but when i am calling **"fromJsonFile" method of "ServiceAccount"** i am getting bellow error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: **Call to private method
>   Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile()** from context '' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\firebase-connection.php:7
>       Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\sb-api\sb_api.php(31):
>   include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-settings.php(362):
>   include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-config.php(90):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-load.php(37):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\admin.php(34):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\index.php(10):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 {main}
>       thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\firebase-connection.php
>   on line 7

```
The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');
$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->create();

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us the version of the firebase-php that you are currently using?

If you are using version lower than 5.x please update to the latest version.

```
https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php
```

It is using php 7.2^. Current wordpress requires 7.3 so it must be updated to latest version

Here is the documentation as well.

```
https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
```

I don't know exactly what the problem is but it seems the error says you can't access a private method, so you should access it by updating it to public or public static method.

Answer (score 0):

For ver 5.x

```
// @see https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.0/troubleshooting.html
$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');

$database = $factory->createDatabase();

// if you want auth
//$auth = $factory->createAuth();
```